# Apache server conflict

Tags: apache, cpanel, httpd.conf

I am getting this error while installing Bitrix24 CRM in server via cPanel "ea-apache24 conflicts with httpd-2.4.6-99.el7.centos.1.x86_64"

I tried removing httpd but was unable to and other websites are also running on this server so i cant remove apache24.

Comment: BTW this will also off-topic on serverfault since you are using a control panel. But the error is self-explanatory - you need to remove the existing Apache instance before you can install a new one.

Comment: Yes it is self explanatory but we are unable to find httpd so removing it is out of question. In our server we have multiple websites that are running and for bitrix24 we have a separate cpanel but still we were unabel to delete httpd.

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to install Bitrix24 on a server that uses cPanel as its web hosting control panel. This installation setup is not recommended, as cPanel has its own built-in services and requirements that can conflict with the requirements of Bitrix24. Since both cPanel and Bitrix24 need certain components configured in specific ways, installing them together on the same server can create conflicts and issues.